# passing the id of half checked node in jstree checkbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jstree

I'm using jstree checkbox plugin in three_state. I've been able to pass the id of the checked node. But for my purpose i need to pass the id of the half selected node as well (id of parent whose children are partially selected). Is there any way i can do this??

I'm using the code below:

```
real_checkboxes_names: function (n) {
    return [("check_" + (n[0].id)), n[0].id]
}
```

Comment: It would be convenient if you'd provide more code (or better, a jsfiddle). Would that be disturbing?

Answer (score 0):

How is document.getElementBId('checkedNodeID').parentNode.id working? Lookup the plugin methods first, otherwise see if the DOM parentNode property can help you (depending on the generated html structure you might need parentNode.parentNode)

Comment: i'm using the below code to pass the id of selected children as form collection. isn't there any way to enter code to pass the id of half state node similarly??
real_checkboxes_names: function (n) {
                      return [("check_" + (n[0].id)), n[0].id]
                    }